# Express: Parsing array of strings in multipart/form data

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multipartform-data, multer

I am trying to send an array of type String and a png file using multipart/form data. I receive my image file and I receive my data via req.body. However the array is of type String, as expected. How do I parse this into an array?

Here's my postman request: 
 
[image]

Here's my console log: 
 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `JSON.parse` to convert string to array.

```js
let tattooGroups= `["Women", "Unisex"]`;
console.log("Without JSON.parse ->  ", typeof tattooGroups);
console.log("With    JSON.parse -> ", typeof JSON.parse(tattooGroups));
console.log("With    JSON.parse, Is Array -> ", Array.isArray(JSON.parse(tattooGroups)));

console.log(JSON.parse(tattooGroups));
```